# python api show aggregates hypervisors in openstack

Tags: python, openstack

I can't get information about availability_zone(aggregate) hypervisors in OpenStack API. I try to list all hypervisors on the same AZ.

```
CLI
openstack aggregate list  
+----+----------------+-------------------+
| ID | Name           | Availability Zone |
+----+----------------+-------------------+
|  3 | zone19         | zone1             |
|  4 | zone20         | zone2             |
|  6 | zone22         | zone3             |
+----+----------------+-------------------+

openstack aggregate show  zone19
+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Field             | Value                                                                |
+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| availability_zone | zone1                                                                 |
| created_at        | 2017-06-22T14:14:55.000000                                           |
| deleted           | False                                                                |
| deleted_at        | None                                                                 |
| hosts             | [u'compute101', u'compute102'] |
| id                | 3                                                                    |
| name              | zone19                                                       |
| properties        |                                                                      |
| updated_at        | None                                                                 |
+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
servers = nova.aggregates.list()
print("servers", servers)

('servers', [<Aggregate: 3>, <Aggregate: 4>, <Aggregate: 6>])
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found solution for my case. It's not really hard but first what i found was how to take JSON from API with information with AZ.

First in openstack CLI:

**-f json**

```
$ openstack aggregate show -f json zone19
```

then response is:

```
{
  "name": "zone19", 
  "availability_zone": "zone1", 
  "deleted": false, 
  "created_at": "2017-06-22T14:14:55.000000", 
  "updated_at": null, 
  "properties": "", 
  "hosts": [
    "compute101", 
    "compute102"
  ], 
  "deleted_at": null, 
  "id": 3
}
```

and in python:

```
aggregates = nova.aggregates.list()    
if aggregates:
       for aggregate in aggregates:

        print("aggregate_name", aggregate.name, aggregate.hosts)


('aggregate_name', u'zone19', [u'compute101',u'compute102'])
```